# Elliptic units as Euler systems

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I’m trying to understand elliptic units in order to work with the Euler systems of the abelian extensions of quadratic imaginary number fields. I’ve looked at few references about the topic, but they define elliptic units from different perspectives. Can anyone suggest a short and comprehensive definition of elliptic units. Thank you.

Comment: Ableism = abelian? Did you look at the Wikipedia article? I believe all references there are in your context precisely, no?

Comment: Yes I did, but I’ve been learning enough about elliptic curbed and their torsion points but I need a clear definition of elliptic units

Comment: It is hard to answer when you do not tell us what "few references" you have looked at so far. I like Rubin's text in the Cetraro notes (LNM 1716).